# Creating new wordpress user using civicrm memberships.?

Tags: wordpress

I am new to civicrm and trying to integrating it with wordpress . Can anyone tell me how can i create user using civicrm .
or when somebody sign up for a membership (trough civicrm) a new gets created in wp.

also once 'CONFIRM CONTRIBUTION' IS CLICKED(membership signup). page goes no where .
it was suppose to goto to 'thankyou ' page which was set in 'contribution page'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a WordPress user with membership signup can be achieved with the below workflow -

Create a [profile](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/profiles/) with fields that you wish to collect during your membership signup process (Primary email address is mandetory) -

In the advanced settings section of your profile you have an option called "WordPress user account registration option?"

CiviCRM help text for this option -

*If you are using this profile as a contact signup form, using it in an online contribution page OR an event registration page, anonymous users will be given the option to create a WordPress User Account as part of completing the form. In addition, you must include a Primary Email Address field in the profile.*

[image]

Once you have created a profile you need to create a [CiviCRM contribution page](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/membership/online-membership-sign-up/) that offers membership and [attach the new profile](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/membership/online-membership-sign-up/#collecting-information-as-part-of-membership-sign-up-the-profiles-tab) that you created.

For WordPress you will also need to check the box "Anyone can register" in the WordPress general settings.

The contribution page will now offer the account creation option when a user is not logged in -

[image]

Comment: thanks @ Anil for the reply .actually i had all of this set up ,still it was not working . actually for free membership case i was trying that.

when i checked 'Execute real-time monetary transactions' .and tried payment with test cards . membersignup finally worked.

Comment: Isn't unchecked 'Execute real-time monetary transactions' box required for Free memberships  signup ?

i dont know where am i going wrong but not able to create free memberships @Anil - MillerTech

Comment: I’ve manged to set up a contribution page that offers free membership on the WordPress demo site - https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org

Be quick to review as this site is restored to its default state periodically.
Free membership settings - https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fmember%2FmembershipType%2Fadd&action=update&id=4&reset=1
Contribution page - https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=5

Comment: Hi @anil -millertech for the reply .i i think the documentation for the same is not updated which caused the this issue. any way thanks for the help

Comment: after making a successful transaction , i could see the newly created members are assigned 'Subscriber'. so in order to assigning them the role of member , should i have to use hooks or is there any other option which can be employed.?

Comment: You will need the WordPress member sync plugin to achieve this –

https://github.com/christianwach/civicrm-wp-member-sync
https://wordpress.org/plugins/civicrm-wp-member-sync/

Would strongly advise to test on a non-production environment at first.

Comment: thanks .
Hello @Anil-Miller Tech  . 
Is it possible in civicrm to create a structure where .
there is a main Branch 
this BRANCH has 4-5 sub branches BRANCH1,BRANCH2,BRANCH3,BRANCH4,BRANCH5
each of sub branches has 4-5 membership type. how to create this structure.??

Comment: @mehta, you are drifting well away from the original question. Please accept my original answer if helped and proceed with asking a new question regarding your branch membership structure. Many thanks

Comment: haha @anil-millertech . i thought of taking your guidance in this regard in the same thread. thanks any way.